# Calculate the distance between following records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view X that return those records:

```
ID   Value
1    8
2    20
3    24
4    80
```

and I need to calculate the distance between each record value and his following. In the last record, (id =4) I should insert default distance of 100.
so I did this query:

```
SELECT a.ID , (a.Value-b.Value) as DistanceToNextRecord
from X as a cross join X as b ON ( a.ID = b.ID-1)
```

and got :

```
ID  DistanceToNextRecord
1   12
2   4
3   56
```

but I don't know how to treat the last record. I need another row :

```
4   100
```

how can I do that?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Removing SQL Server tags.  `cross join` with an `on` clause looks a lot like MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do this type of calculation using a correlated subquery (unless your database supports `lead()`:

```
select x.id, x.value,
       (select x2.value
        from x x2
        where x2.id > x.id
        order by x2.id
        limit 1
       ) - x.value as DistanceToNextRecord
from x x;
```

This will return `NULL` for the last row.

EDIT:

If you can be sure that the `id`s are sequential with no gaps, then you can modify your query to use a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT a.ID , (a.Value-b.Value) as DistanceToNextRecord
from X a left join
     X b
    ON a.ID = b.ID - 1;
```

Comment: ok great, the left out join is ok.
now I got null in the distance..
there is option to insert the default value in this query?
or I need another one that will run the nulls..

I try something like that:
CASE (a.Value-b.Value)
     WHEN null THEN 100
     ELSE (a.Value - b.Value)
 end

but it's not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Using a left join will allow you to pull back the last row which has no match in your join condition.  You can then use `ISNULL` to default it to 100

I'm using SQL Server but mySQL should be able to do the same thing.

```
DECLARE @myView TABLE (ID int, VALUE int)

INSERT INTO @myView VALUES  (1,8)
INSERT INTO @myView VALUES  (2,20)
INSERT INTO @myView VALUES  (3,24)
INSERT INTO @myView VALUES  (4,80)

SELECT a.ID, ISNULL((b.VALUE-a.VALUE),100) AS DistanceToNextRecord
FROM @myView AS a LEFT JOIN @myView AS b ON (a.ID = b.ID-1)
```